# How do I configure a Python3 interpreter in IntelliJ IDEA

Tags: python-3.x, intellij-idea, virtualenv

IntelliJ IDEA 16 when you create a virtualenv, you can call it as an SDK and automatically runs and validates language, libraries and everything that you need for that project. This is helpful since the lint and other libraries become available on the IDE.

The Problem:
I have a machine that has 2 python installations (python2 and python3).
I can set up virtual environments in those different versions but  when I want to create a project SDK from a virtualenv where python 3 is being use  get the message "Cannot Save Settings" "Please specify different sdk name".

The same process that I use to set up the virutalenv on python 2 is the same for python 3 but this error keeps happening.

I would appreciate any help on how to configure that. I have looked all around the web and forums that talk about intelliJ and the SDK configurations but all of them  are for python 2.7 and not when you have two python version installed on the same machine and using virutalenvs so set it up.

Comment: I was able to solve my issue with IntelliJ and Python3.  The problem was on the updates that get applied on my machine.  For some reason it cloned one of my virtual environments. Because of that when I was trying to create a new SDK on intelliJ it was asking me to rename one of the clones.  After doing that change, the SDK started working with out problems.